# A-frame VR 3d object positioning using yaw and pitch

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality

I'm working on an a-frame project which requires me to position several 3d objects in 360 virtual reality. Traditionally it is done using:

```
<a-entity position="x y z"></a-entity>
```

But what I need is to use yaw and pitch to position the 3d objects. So far I haven't a-frame supporting this workflow.

Is it possible to position 3d objects in a-frame 3d space using yaw and pitch?

Answer (score 1):

make the object that you want to position, a child of another object (the parent). Position the child at (5, 0, 0) in the coordinate system of the parent. Rotate the parent (ie change yaw and pitch), and the position of the child changes.

[glitch](https://glitch.com/~move-ball-rotation) here